# how to get string after special character(@) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mail address and i want to save the domain name.How to fetch.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  String functions are, alas, highly database dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following:

```
select
substring_index(ColName, '@', -1)
from table
```

Comment: OK @Keerthi. Glad to know and if it worked, mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use `substring_index()`.  To get the string after the *last* (or only) `'@'`, you would use:

```
select substring_index(str, '@', -1)
from t;
```

In SQL Server, one method would look like:

```
select substring(col, charindex('@', col + '@') + 1, len(col))
from t;
```

Note that if there is no `'@'`, then this returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server:

```
substring(mail,charindex('@',mail)+1,len(mail))
```